# Can access SQL Database via SSMS, but not via VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, ssms-2012

I have an `Azure database`, `SSMS 2012`, and `VS 2013`. I have created the appropriate logins and users for myself and a colleague using the server login to access the `Azure database`. However, for reasons unknown to me, I can only access the database through `SSMS`. In VS I can access and login into the server just fine.  But, when we click to expand the database, it produces and 'x' and denies showing any related tables, etc.  Yet, from SSMS all is accessible with no problem.  My colleague can access the database on his machine via SSMS or `VS 2013 Community Edition`.  The problem seems to exist on only my machine and only with respect to the created logins.  I can access the database fine using the admin credentials.  I have attempted reinstalling VS, but it hasn't helped.  Thoughts from anyone?

Comment: Might be updates. I'd check if Tools->Extensions and Updates Window says any updates on SQL Server or Azure SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't the issue.  It's up to day as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I cannot access the database because the Azure db I created is the 2014 (v12) version.  I have SSMS 2012 (v11) loaded on my machine which is not compatible with the v12 db.  Hence, the issues.  The short of it is: I need to update to SSMS 2014 and reload VS afterwards since it partially relies on SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

To Access Azure on your system with VS 2013

- Very first please allow your IP in Azure SQL database firewall.
- Connect Azure Subscription in Server explorer.
- Go to SQL database and select your database and right click on that and select     "Open in SQL Server Object explorer".
- In SQL Server Object explorer your database will reopen with all required option and table list.

Comment: I had already tried these, and I went thru the motions just to be sure, again, but still no help.  I should have included (and will edit the original to say) that I can logon via VS with the admin credentials just fine.  It is only any other login that won't work.  And, only on my machine and in VS.